# Change ownership or permissions of external drive using username and password

Tags: permissions, password

There must be an answer to this, but I really could not find it anywhere.

I have an external hard drive with data from an older computer, i.e. I have the old username and password, but these do not match user and password from my current box.

Can I either change the ownership of the older drive to copy the files onto my newer system? Or can I set permissions of the older files using the old user and password?

Should I create the old user in my new box? (Sounds clunky...)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access to your current system, it would be simplest to change the owner of the external drive's contents. 
If the drive is mounted at `/mnt`,a simple `sudo chown $USER /mnt -R` should do the trick.

Of course, if the system is intended to be used later on, this would cause problems. So use the command only on those directories you need. Leave alone any directories owned by `root`. You can fix other permissions later.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. Still have permissions denied.

Comment: My bad. Was really tired. It works, just have to do it recursively. `sudo chown -R $USER /media/the_external_drive`